# Index Match array formula over a number of rows and columns VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Sorry I am new here. I am working on a project part of which is I have to find a certain keyword in a range (several rows and columns) and then return corresponding value from that row.

The simplified version (with reference to single sheet) is:
`{INDEX($C$2:$C$4~MIN(IF($C$2:$E$4=A2~ROW($C$2:$E$4)-1)))}`

And the code version is:

```
'CTM is another sheet
'SCF is this sheet    
.Range(.Cells(2, SCFCols + 1), Cells(SCFRows, SCFCols + 1)).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & _
    CTMDataSheet & "!$A1:A$" & CTMRows & ",MIN(IF(" & CTMDataSheet & "!$C$2:" & .Cells(CTMRows, CTMCols).Address & _
    "= A2,ROW(" & CTMDataSheet & "!$C$2:" & .Cells(CTMRows, CTMCols).Address & ")-1)))"
```

The error I am getting is "Unable to set FormulaArray property of range class"

Comment: what Excel settings do you have ? shouldn't `INDEX($C$2:$C$4~MIN(IF($C$2:$E$4=A2~ROW($C$2:$E$4)-1)))` be `INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MIN(IF($C$2:$E$4=A2,ROW($C$2:$E$4)-1)))`

Comment: It's working fine with my test, is `CTMDataSheet as String` ? `CTMRows` , `CTMCols`, `SCFRows` and `SCFCols` defined `As Integer` (or `Long`) ? Did you mean to use `.FormulaArray` ? cause in your simplified verions you don't have the `{}` , indicating you are looking to use an array

Comment: @Shai Rado, all the variables are defined as you suggested and yes it is meant to be an array formula (editing simplified version now). Now it's showing "Unable to set formula array property of range class". I have "~" as separator instead of ",".

Comment: @RahulChawla when using vba you need to use American English notation.  Only use `,`, do not use the `~`.  When the formula is placed Excel will make the changes.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have used `,` everywhere in VBA code. Code is in the question text for your reference.

Comment: You are missing a `.` in front of the second `Cells(...` in the Range you are trying to set.

Comment: Oh! The silly mistake we do after 7-8 hours of code! Thanks it solved the issue. @ScottCraner please add your comment as answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: Since it was a simple typo I will leave my answer as a comment.  Glad to have helped.  And don't feel bad, we have all chased silly typos.